# Using curses, how do I update the screen or wait for a key?

Tags: python, multithreading, ncurses

How do I update the screen or wait for a key at the same time? I'm using unicurses on Python but I think I would have the same problem in C.
Here's what I want to do in pseudo code:

```
function startScreen(){
   stdscr = initscr()
   while True{
      - Update screen using a variable that is constantly changing (probably by a thread, right?)
      - Get a key with getch() - to close or interact with the screen
   }
}
```

My problem is that the screen doesn't update unless something happens, like resizing the screen or pressing a key. I was thinking about using the while loop (and a time.sleep(1)?) to update the screen and a thread to wait for keys. Is that possible? I don't know much about threads, that's why I'm asking. Is there a simpler way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done without any complicated multithreading. There is a function `curses.halfdelay` that can be also found in the unicurses library that you use. It takes the number of tenths of a second to wait until continuing. https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.halfdelay

Here is an example code that refreshes every half a second unless there is a button that has been pressed, in which case it updates immediately.

```
import curses
scr = curses.initscr()
curses.halfdelay(5)           # How many tenths of a second are waited, from 1 to 255
curses.noecho()               # Wont print the input
while True:
    char = scr.getch()        # This blocks (waits) until the time has elapsed,
                              # or there is input to be handled
    scr.clear()               # Clears the screen
    if char != curses.ERR:    # This is true if the user pressed something
        scr.addstr(0, 0, chr(char))
    else:
        scr.addstr(0, 0, "Waiting")
```